# How to remove this cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am creating a cookie, but I need to remove A cookie based on a onclick event that I am trying to set, but is not working.

Here is how I am setting the cookie. Which works fine.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
 $(window).load(function(){
 $(".filter input").each(function() {
     var mycookie = $.cookie($(this).attr('name'));
     if (mycookie && mycookie == "true") {
         $(this).prop('checked', mycookie);
     }
 });
 $(".filter input").change(function() {
     $.cookie($(this).attr("name"), $(this).prop('checked'), {
         path: '/',
         expires: 365
     });
 });

 });//]]>
```

And then to delete I am trying to remove the cookie on click event based on an ID with out any luck, I am just not sure where I am going wrong here, would this work... ??? $.removecookie($(this).attr('name'), null, { path: '/' }); see my code below.

```
 <script>
    jQuery('#dnn_ctr555_ProductSearch_rpData_cmdAdvReset_0').click(function()  {
          $.removeCookie($(this).attr('name'), { path: '/' });
     }
</script>
```

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/23nUZ/5/ any help would be awesome.

Comment: I can't find an element called 'dnn_ctr555_ProductSearch_rpData_cmdAdvSearch_0'.

Comment: Also
    $("#dnn_ctr555_ProductSearch_rpData_cmdAdvSearch_0").change(function () {
is better than
    document.getElementById("dnn_ctr555_ProductSearch_rpData_cmdAdvSearch_0").onchange = function () {

Comment: It now works for me, how ever I am unsure where dnn_ctr555_ProductSearch_rpData_cmdAdvSearch_0 should be.

Comment: I updated the fiddle, but I will try your suggestion.

Comment: I suggest you use console.log("sdkbnsd"); or breakpoints to check and see if the cookie delete code is actually run. Also, you will need to reload the page in order to see any changes.

Comment: So I updated the fiddle and its not working, I also used .removeCookie to see if that might help...

Comment: There is still no element I can see called 'dnn_ctr555_ProductSearch_rpData_cmdAdvSearch_0'

Comment: On which event or button click you have to delete the cookie? There is no element with id `dnn_ctr555_ProductSearch_rpData_cmdAdvSearch_0`

Comment: I am using the jQuery cookie plugin.